# Python list.append changing elements afterwards

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

For `args= ['', '0', 'P1', 'with', '10']` and `students=[['1', '2', '3', 6]]`  it prints:

```
[[['1', '2', '3', 6]]]
[[['10', '2', '3', 6]]]
```

The expected output was :

```
[[['1', '2', '3', 6]]]
[[['1', '2', '3', 6]]]
```

But it somehow changes the `backup_list` any quick solutions?

```
backup_list.append(students[:])
print(backup_list)
students[int(args[1])][0] = args[4]
print(backup_list)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[:]` make a shallow copy. You need a deep copy:

```
import copy

backup_list.append(copy.deepcopy(students))
```

Full program:

```
import  copy

backup_list = []
args= ['', '0', 'P1', 'with', '10']
students=[['1', '2', '3', 6]]
backup_list.append(copy.deepcopy(students))
print(backup_list)
students[int(args[1])][0] = args[4]    
print(backup_list)
```

Output:

```
[[['1', '2', '3', 6]]]
[[['1', '2', '3', 6]]]
```

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) explains the difference between shallow and deep copy:

> A shallow copy constructs a new compound object and then 
>   (to the extent possible) inserts references into it to the objects found in
>   the original.
>
> A deep copy constructs a new compound object and then, recursively, inserts
>   copies into it of the objects found in the original.

Comment: Thanks a lot it works, but can you explain more in deep why it does and why it doesn't with a shallow copy :3?